# Two firewalls on Debian server?

Tags: security, debian, firewall

Is there an improvement of security when using two firewalls? I have the option to configure a firewall from the hoster for my Debian 9 server
What happens if I enable ufw on my server? Does it improve the security or is there a possibility it might end in a conflict between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ufw is a front end for netfilter, there is a good chance the hoster's firewall is iptables.
There is no security improvement for having two firewalls on a linux system, you should rather use the one you prefer.